# Primefaces Chart shows cryptic letters on the axis

Tags: jsf, primefaces, linechart

I have a chart with a date axis and a quantity axis. Both axis show cryptic letters in the labelling. The problem occurs in Edge and Google Chrome, Firefox displays it correctly.

The problem is also seen at the Primefaces showcase after view times refeshing the site (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/chart/line.xhtml)
[image: Primefaces Showcase Problem]

Firefox (as expected):

[image: Firefox as expected]

Chrome and Edge with cryptic letters:

[image: Chrome and Edge with cryptic letters]

My code is:

xhtml

```
<p:chart id="chrtAuswertung" type="line" model="#{auswertungenOrdnerBean.dateModel}" widgetVar="chrtAuswertung" style="height:400px; margin-bottom: 2em;" />
```

Bean:

```
dateModel = new LineChartModel();
 DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Datum");
 axis.setTickAngle(-50);
 axis.setTickFormat("%d.%m.%y");
 axis.setMin(localDateStart.toString());
 axis.setMax(localDateEnde.toString());

 dateModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
```

Versions used:

- Google Chrome Browser Version 119.0.6045.124
- Edge Version 120.0.2210.91
- Firefox Version 117.0.1 (64-Bit)
- Primefaces 6.1.1

Does anybody know that problem and has a solution?

Comment: "The problem is also seen at the Primefaces showcase". Works for me.

Comment: I added a screenshot from the problem at Edge browser.

Comment: It's still working for me. PrimeFaces 6 is quite old. You will be better of upgrading and using the new Chart.js component.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a solution for the moment.

Comment: Those legacy jQuery Charts were buggy and not up to date for newer browsers.  You will continue to run into these issues which is why PrimeFaces dropped those jQuery Charts in later versions for Charts.JS